# How to write a search text implementation in Java

Tags: java, search, hidden-characters

I am trying to write a search text implementation in Java

With the below code below:

```
public String log(Object... source) {...//simple System.out.println for debugging purposes}
public boolean searchInLoweCase(CharSequence searchTag, CharSequence containsTag) {
   var contains = containsTag.toString().contains(searchTag);
   log("search", "searchTag", searchTag, contains, "containsTag", containsTag);
   IntStream.range(0, searchTag.length()).forEachOrdered(charIdx -> {
       log("search",
        "searchTag[" + charIdx + "].charAt/codePointAt/int", searchTag.charAt(charIdx), searchTag.codePointAt(charIdx), "as", (int) searchTag.charAt(charIdx),
        "containsTag[" + charIdx + "].charAt/codePointAt/int", containsTag.charAt(charIdx), searchTag.codePointAt(charIdx), "as", (int) containsTag.charAt(charIdx)
       );
   });
   return contains;
 }
```

For input "i":
[image]

the output is

```
{searchTag, i, true, containsTag, i̇letişim}
{searchTag[0].charAt/codePointAt/int, i, 105, as, 105, containsTag[0].charAt/codePointAt/int, i, 105, as, 105}
```

For input "il":
[image]

the output is

```
 {searchTag, il, false, containsTag, i̇letişim}
 {searchTag[0].charAt/codePointAt/int, i, 105, as, 105, containsTag[0].charAt/codePointAt/int, i, 105, as, 105}
 {searchTag[1].charAt/codePointAt/int, l, 108, as, 108, containsTag[1].charAt/codePointAt/int, ̇, 108, as, 775}
```

Here you can see the hidden character there.
I tried to remove the hidden character with [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031531/remove-hidden-character-and-special-character-java-javascript);
however it did not work.

Did you exprienced it before?

Comment: Don’t use chars, use code points.

Comment: @Boris the Spider.  After using the code points, i could see the same numbers. I will try to implement search function with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implementation**
To search strings, one can use equals or contains after uppercasing them with locale tuned.

**The Bug:**
However, I figured that there is a [bug](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) in JDK and Javascript for turkish and german character convertions.

**JavaScript:**
In JavaScript, one should detect the locale first:

```
var lng = navigator.language; //tr
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850232/turkish-case-conversion-in-javascript) answer, one can use below code to uppercase strings in native javascript.

```
"iıöçşğü".toLocaleUpperCase('tr-TR'); //İIÖÇŞĞÜ
```

**JAVA | GWT:**
In Java, one should detect the locale first: (like [here](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.charset/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/api/charset/server/TS_CharSetUtils.java))

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("tr");
```

Or in Java GWT,  one should detect the locale first: (like [here](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.charset/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/api/charset/client/TGC_CharSetUtils.java))

```
LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName().contains("tr");
```

Then, according to language detected, If it is an unsupported language, he should use the below fix: (like [here](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.charset/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/api/charset/client/TGS_CharSetCast.java))

```
"iıöçşğü".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT); //İIÖÇŞĞÜ
```